# How to Load a Raster Image in PyQt without Changing Bit Depth?

Tags: python, raster, pyqt6, rasterio

I am working on a PyQt application where I need to display a raster image using QtGui.QPixmap. However, I am facing an issue when the raster image has a 32-bit depth. I get an error saying:

```
foo: Sorry, cannot handle images with 32-bit samples.
```

I've tried using the Rasterio library to read the image into a NumPy array, then converting it to a QtGui.QImage. While this approach works, it requires me to change the bit depth of the image to 8 bits, which I would like to avoid.
Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
import rasterio
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import numpy as np

class Modify:
    @staticmethod
    def open_image(path):
        with rasterio.open(path) as src:
            array = src.read(1)
        return array

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ImageProcess")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

    def drawItems(self):
        self.image = Modify.open_image("path/to/image.tif")
        self.image = (self.image / np.max(self.image) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        height, width = self.image.shape
        bytes_per_line = width
        image_format = QtGui.QImage.Format_Grayscale8

        qimage = QtGui.QImage(self.image.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, image_format)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
```

Is there any way to load and display the raster image in PyQt without altering its original bit depth?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, there is not, since the current [QImage.Format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#Format-enum) only supports up to 16 bits for gray scale images (`Format_Grayscale16`, since Qt 5.13). I'm no expert, so I may be completely wrong about this, but I'm not even sure if current systems are actually capable of *displaying* gray scale images with that type of resolution, even considering modern HDR support where available. If you need some level of inspection/editing on the original data, then keep the source data as reference and use it when required.